# Find some rational number $b$ such that $a<b^2<2$ where $1<a<2$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$ be a rational number and $1<a<2$. Prove that there exists a rational number $b$ such that $a<b^2<2$.

Comment: Use the fact that rationals are dense in the real line.

Comment: the density tell me that there exists $c$ such that $a<c<2$.

Comment: Use the density to find a rational $b$ such that $\sqrt{a}<b<\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 6):

If $1<a<2$, then $1<\sqrt a<\sqrt2$ (note that $\sqrt a$ need not be rational). Since $\sqrt a < \sqrt 2$, and the rationals are dense in the real line, there is a rational number $b \in (\sqrt a, \sqrt 2)$. We then have
$$
1<\sqrt a < b < \sqrt 2
$$
which implies
$$
1<a<b^2 < 2
$$

Comment: I'd like to see a $b$ written explicitly in terms of $a$. Newton's method for $\sqrt a$ may help.

Comment: @lhf That's not an easy thing to do, since $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, $\sqrt a$ _may_ be irrational, and you want a rational number in the interval $(\sqrt a, \sqrt2)$. You can probably do it with floor functions, but it won't be pretty at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "constructive" proof:

From $a<2$ it follows that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{a}<3$, and therefore that
$$\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{a}={2-a\over\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{a}}>{2-a\over3}\ .$$
Choose an ${\displaystyle \ n>{3\over 2-a}\ }$. Then
$$\sqrt{2n^2}-\sqrt{an^2}>{2-a\over3}n>1\ .$$
It follows that there is an integer $p$ with
$$\sqrt{an^2}<p<\sqrt{2n^2}\ .$$ The number ${\displaystyle \ b:={p\over n}\in{\mathbb Q}\ }$ then satisfies $a<b^2<2$.